# Ways to find a tutor for 1st year University student

Tags: training

I tried searching here (and SO) without much luck. I also stared at the yellow box to the right and think this question is relatively on topic and can be answered.

A co-worker asked me if I had any suggestions for how to find a tutor for his son.  In this specific case, it was for Eclipse and Java, but it got me thinking about good general strategies one could use in situations like this.

He preferred a local 1-to-1, but I suppose online might be a reasonable (or perhaps more likely) alternative.

Any suggested strategies?

Comment: How much is he looking to pay, and what country/city?

Comment: I'd say this is off-topic. Finding a tutor (in any subject) is not a subjective software development issue.

Comment: @Anna ...but finding a tutor in programming... possibly is?

Comment: @Alison I don't think it is, honestly. Replace "Eclipse and Java" with "chemistry" in the question and nothing else changes. The question has a couple Java-related keywords in it, but at its core it's not a software development issue. The fact that it draws generic answers like "look in a university newspaper" is another sign that the question isn't sufficiently programmer-specific.

Comment: @Anna not sure I see your point - you can do that with lots of Qs, e.g. "Resources for functional programming beginner" -> "Resources for chemistry beginner"; "What are the technical contributions of the pornography industry?" -> "What are the chemical contributions of the pornography industry?"; "What defines a standard?"; "Is it possible to become a good programmer if you don't like math?" -> "Is it possible to become a good chemist if you don't like math?"  It's not the OP's fault that the answers are generic - if he needed to ask then he probably didn't know that the question's "generic".

Comment: @Alison In your examples, replacing "programmer" with "chemist" actually changes the question (i.e. resources for functional programmers aren't the same as resources for beginner chemists). Finding a tutor requires the same approach regardless of the field.

Comment: You've not really addressed my point that the OP isn't to know that in this case the question may be non-specific to programmers. Also, I don't think it's clear that this is in fact the case.

Comment: @Alison My original comment serves the purpose of alerting the OP (and others).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I alluded to this in my question, but I really did ponder whether this was appropriate before I asked. I even considered StackExchangeJeopardying the question so that it sounded more like a career advice question.

In this particular case, in addition to the "generic" answers (which were also helpful), there was at least one that I think is essentially a programmer centric answer (i.e. Alison's JUG suggestion, which I think is clever).

With that being said, it's really nice to see rational, respectful debate even when people disagree - cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tutoring agencies are normally a good place to look, if you're willing to pay.

If it's specifically for e.g. Java development, then you might find a local Java User Group that you could get in touch with.

Answer (score 3):

How about a comp. sci. classmate? -- either in the same class or a year or two older? I think this may be your best option for 1-1. They will work relatively affordably, have taken the same classes as your friend's son, and your friend's son may relate to a classmate better.

Answer (score 1):

At least where I went people offering themselves as tutors would put ads in the University newspapers, mailing lists or hallways. He or she may post an ad looking for a tutor.

It was somewhat common for freshman that were having trouble with some disciplines to look for tutors. Usually senior students or graduate students who needed the money would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

At a university, I would suggest contacting the academic advising office (or department office) and/or student organizations within the department that offers courses in the subject matter that you need tutoring in.

The people there might be able to find available tutors or at least provide you to people who would be good.